# Is there any podcast player that supports bookmarks?

Tags: windows, podcasts

**Is there any podcast player that supports bookmarks?**

By bookmark I mean during the podcast playback you can create bookmarks that you can go to later.
It would be great if you also could make notes in the bookmarks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd have a look at  Angels Vox: http://www.superutils.com/products/angels-vox/ and  Juice: http://juicereceiver.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

Mine ([Creative Zen Style 300](http://uk.store.creative.com/entertainment-devices-mp3-players/zen-style-300/948-19238.aspx)) supports up to 10 (I think) bookmarks. But there is no ability to add notes.

Comment: I'm using windows.