# Linux Podcast Playback with Resume Capability

Tags: linux, ubuntu, podcasts, playback

I'm asking a question similar to but distinct from [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/260250/is-there-any-podcast-player-that-supports-bookmarks)

Is there a Linux player that can resume playback of a podcast episode where it was last left off? This is the default behavior of iTunes for example.

In particular, is there a way to achieve this capability on Banshee or other major Linux podcast clients?

Comment: to my knowledge, Amarok should be able to do it.

Comment: Amarok doesn't appear to do that. I wish it did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Miro](http://www.getmiro.com/) should do this.

Comment: Not only does it do so, but it does so in a very intuitive and user friendly way. Thank you for point me to Miro!

Answer (score 0):

[Panucci](http://gpodder.org/panucci/) advertises this capability. It actually looks like the perfect fit but is not available for Ubuntu as a package yet, so I'll wait.

> With Panucci, you can play audio books, podcasts and live concerts. It
>   will automatically resume the playback from the position where you
>   stopped last time. Bookmarks are also supported. The interface has
>   elements big enough to be used with your fingers. If you installed
>   support for screen rotation, Panucci does support portrait mode in
>   addition to landscape mode.

[image]