# Running podcasts on Ubuntu without iTunes

Tags: podcasts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Linux Podcast Playback with Resume Capability](https://superuser.com/questions/280895/linux-podcast-playback-with-resume-capability)

Hi I am trying to view the podcasts on http://itunes.apple.com/itunes-u/programming-massively-parallel/id384233322#ls=1  Is there a way to see these podcasts without using iTunes.

I am using Ubuntu 10.10. I tried to install Apple iTunes with wine but the installation did not work correctly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linux Podcast Playback with Resume Capability](http://superuser.com/questions/280895/linux-podcast-playback-with-resume-capability) also see [Podcast desktop app](http://superuser.com/questions/1767/podcast-desktop-app)

Comment: The RSS feed for that is http://deimos3.apple.com/WebObjects/Core.woa/Feed/itunes.stanford.edu-dz.4331559912.04331559914.  You can find this out, by opening it with iTunes, and right clicking and choose 'copy iTunesU URL'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tried the process described at http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/06/how-to-import-itunes-podcasts-in-rhythmbox/ in VLC and it worked great. It uses a site called [Feed Flipper](http://picklemonkey.net/flipper/convert.php) to convert the iTunes feed to a simple RSS. As a side note I pasted several other converted feeds into Firefox to look at the results and saw that it presented the non-iTunes feed for them that I was able to use directly (in my case in Google Reader).

Comment: An itunes feed is RSS, there shouldn't need to be any conversion.  iTunes generally just serves up the standard RSS podcast feed that is submitted by the Podcast owner.

Comment: Easy enough, I have never checked out the itunes store before. Where on that web page do you right click to get the RSS feed?

Comment: That is the really annoying part.  AFAIK, you cannot get the feed URL from the web page version of the iTunes store, but it is there, just hidden.  Some publishers will provide a link to their web page, and on their web page you can get the RSS feed.  For [twit](http://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/this-week-in-tech-mp3-edition/id73329404), click the 'podcast website' link, then find the  feed on the twit.tv page.  I am a bit confused what Feed Flipper is doing.

Comment: Thank you for this excellent solution! This worked for me!

Comment: @Zoredache - As far as I can tell from the feeds I've tried it is just exposing the source feed that you are describing and passing it along on the fly. I just found it cool because I'm a podcast junkie but don't have iTunes so figured browsing http://itunes.apple.com/us/genre/podcasts/id26 was a closed door to me. I will probably use the exposed source feeds but it definitely opens the door with just a couple clicks.